# Camel IgniteMessagingComponent

Tags: apache-camel, ignite, spring-boot-test

Hello I am trying use camel ignite messaging component to produce and consume the messages across the ignite cluster.

Please find the sample code :

```
IgniteMessagingComponent igniteMessagingComponent = IgniteMessagingComponent.fromConfiguration(igniteConfiguration);
igniteMessagingComponent.setCamelContext(camelContext);
igniteMessagingComponent.setIgniteConfiguration(igniteConfiguration);
igniteMessagingComponent.setIgnite(ignite);
igniteMessagingComponent.setIgniteConfiguration(igniteConfiguration);

Endpoint enp = igniteMessagingComponent.createEndpoint("ignite-messaging:topic?Topic=testtopicname&SendMode=ORDERED&Timeout=30000");

producerTemplate.sendBody(enp,"Test");
```

I am getting below error : `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CamelContext must be specified on: Message[]`

Please suggest what I have missed.

Comment: I've never seen Camel integration in the wild so I would very much like to know.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Could you please post the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Got resolved it was configuration issue the way I have started my camel ignite-messaging subscriber's endpoint. After setting CamelContext explicitly to the endpoint It work successfully.

Sample code :

```
    **IgniteMessagingComponent igniteMessagingComponent= 
    IgniteMessagingComponent.fromConfiguration(igniteConfiguration);
    igniteMessagingComponent.setIgnite(ignite);
    Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap();
    IgniteMessagingEndpoint psenp = new IgniteMessagingEndpoint("ignite-messaging:", "topic1", parameters,igniteMessagingComponent);
psenp.setCamelContext(camelContext);
    from(psenp).process(processor).end();**
```